# Creating a Kotlin data class without parameters

Tags: json, list, kotlin, json-deserialization, data-class

hope I can get some valued assistance with a little issue I'm trying to work.

I've got an API endpoint which is sending data with the following request schema:

```
{
  "type": String,
  "coordinates": [
    0.949492,
    48.77163
  ]
}
```

As can be seen; the coordinates from the search are provided as two INT values, without parameters.

I'm trying to create an automated test for this, and I've put the above in a data class so it can be used all over the suite as-needed.

My data class is currently looking like the below example, but I don't know how to properly define a list for coordinates without a val or var parameter. I've defined it as a var called "list" for now so it stops throwing compilation errors. How should I be representing this list of coordinates?

```
data class SearchRequest(
    val type: String,
    val coordinates: List<Coordinates>
)


data class Coordinates(
    var list: Int
)
```

Comment: It looks like it's just a list of floating point numbers, so you could define `val coordinates: List<Float>` in your first class and you don't need a second class.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback. Also suggested by another, so definitely the way to go! Thanks again.

Comment: You might have realised already, but a *data class* requires at least one parameter, and *all* its constructor parameters need to be a `val` or `var`. That's what makes it a data class - all its *data* is the stuff in the constructor params, and that's what's used in its generated `copy` function, as well as its `equals`/`hashCode`/`toString` overrides. So if you ever *do* want a class with normal, non-`val`/`var` constructor parameters, you need a regular class! (Or maybe a builder function that can set up a *data class* after constructing it, using your extra params to poke at it)

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is a list of `Float` values, there is no need to create a separate class for that, `Float` can be used:

```
data class SearchRequest(
    val type: String,
    val coordinates: List<Float>
)
```

Comment: Ahh brilliant. So simple, so easy. Your help and answer are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, you can also download a plugin from android studio that does this for you by just pasting the API's JSON format. The plugin name is JSON to Kotlin class converter, I think.